# objective c Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRApp' crashlytics

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

i am integrated firebase crashlytics framework in my project. in my pod file i am adding this framworks.

```rb
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
    
pod 'Crashlytics'
    
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    
pod 'Firebase/Core'
    
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

in AppDelegate.m file i am import the firebase like this.

```objectivec
@import Firebase;
```

in application did finish launching with options method i am calling this method.

```objectivec
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
       
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
[FIRApp configure];

return YES;

}
```

in `[FIRApp configure];` i got this error.

> Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRApp'

can any body help me please.

Comment: Just to rule out the usual suspects: you did run `pod install` and you opened the `.xcworkspace`, not `.xcodeproj` after that, right?

Comment: Can you remove pod Crashlytics, and run pod update.

Clean the build (ctrl+shift+k) and then try again.